# How to create a button near the address bar?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am designing a firefox extension, and I want to add a button near the address bar. And then I need to attach a bookmarklet to that button.

Someone can tell me what APIs do I have to use to create that button and to add the bookmarklet ?

Comment: I found soulution :-). [Library moz-urlbarbutton](https://github.com/voxpelli/moz-urlbarbutton)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example that uses Erik Vold's toolbarbutton library to add a button near the addressbar:

```
const data = require("self").data;
const tabs = require("tabs");

exports.main = function(options) {
    var btn = require("toolbarbutton").ToolbarButton({
        id: 'my-toolbar-button',
        label: 'Add skull!',
        image: data.url('skull-16.png'),
        onCommand: function() {
            if (typeof(tabs.activeTab._worker) == 'undefined') {
                let worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
                    contentScript: 'self.port.on("sayhello", function() { alert("Hello world!"); })'
                });
                tabs.activeTab._worker = worker;
            }
            tabs.activeTab._worker.port.emit("sayhello");
        }
    });

    if (options.loadReason === "install") {
    btn.moveTo({
      toolbarID: "nav-bar",
      forceMove: false // only move from palette
    });
  }
};
```

You can also see this as a runnable example on the Add-on Builder site:

https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1044724/latest/

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to add the button on the left side of the address bar ?

Comment: xRobot: not using that library. Wladimir: noted.

Comment: xRobot: when using the `moveTo` method use the `insertBefore` attribute.